# A fix for AudioSessionInitialize Deprecated?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Apple did not post any alternative code for this on the Apple Developer site.

Comment: I think you have to use AVAudioSession. But I am not sure if this also initializes the audio session.

Comment: correction: apple docs clearly discusses the deprecation and it's alternative here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/audiotoolbox/reference/audiosessionservicesreference/index.html

Answer (score 11):

You should use AVAudioSession.

To replace the functionality provided by deprecated AudioSessionInitialize (e.g. if you need to specify AudioSessionInterruptionListener callback) you can subscribe for AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioSessionDidChangeInterruptionType:)
        name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]];
```

And implement your audioSessionDidChangeInterruptionType: handler like:

```
- (void)audioSessionDidChangeInterruptionType:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    AVAudioSessionInterruptionType interruptionType = [[[notification userInfo]
        objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
    if (AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan == interruptionType)
    {
    }
    else if (AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded == interruptionType)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

1.
for this code

```
AudioSessionInitialize( NULL, NULL, interruptionCallback, self );
```

replace with

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

2.
fro this code

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
AudioSessionSetProperty(
        kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
        sizeof(sessionCategory),
        &sessionCategory
        );
```

replace with

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
     setCategory:sessionCategory error:nil];
```

Comment: The first line in the second code snapshot should be changed to `NSString* sessionCategory = AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord;`

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent code to

```
// C way
UInt32 category = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback ;
OSStatus result = AudioSessionSetProperty(
  kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(category), &category ) ;

if( result ) // handle the error
```

Is

```
// Objective-C way
NSError *nsError;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
  setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&nsError];

if( nsError != nil )  // handle the error
```

Comment: Doing this gives error "Use of undeclared identifier AVAudioSession"

Comment: Added AVFoundation to framework and included in the header file to fix.

Answer (score 1):

In swift we can add the following

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        } catch {
            print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
        }
```

from: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
} catch let error {
    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
}

do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .spokenAudio)
} catch let error {
    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```