# how to get audio session initialization error status since AudioSessionInitialize was deprecated?

Tags: ios, audio, error-handling, ios7, deprecated

On start app i called `AudioSessionInitialize` and check result value.
If it was `kAudioSessionInitializationError` then i informed user that application can not work properly cause audio does not work.

But since iOS 7 this function was deprecated.
It was similar question before: [A fix for AudioSessionInitialize Deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19710046/751932) but... it has no any mention about how to get initialization error status.

And of course, i know how to initialize audio session without this function: Just calling `[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]` cause hidden call of `AudioSessionInitialize`. But it returns non zero value anyway. So new interface does not allow to get initialization error status.

upd: I'm not sure it's important but i receive message to stdout (which i redirected to log file) while call with error happens:

> ERROR:    [7971] 146: Unable to talk to server: error 0x10000003
>   (268435459)

explaination why i need this:

It happens very rarely (less then 0,1% of case) but it happens for any firmware. Last case registered for iOS 7.0.3 - so it's actual return value still (btw, first case registered for first firmware my app supported: iOS 2.2). It's important feature (cause i develop alarm clock) - it allows to know user about issues in the evening and not in the morning (cause in the morning this issue will cause oversleep).

Comment: Your shared answer already provided a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19772893/188331

Comment: no - solution does not contain any mention about error status, and i wrote about in my question.

Comment: Are you still using the `AudioSessionInitialize` ?

Comment: I mean you shouldn't use deprecated class & function.

Comment: Of course! This is main reason why i asked this question. I don't see any way to get initialization error status. Fixed my question to clear this moment